# Problema al convertir una imagen en URI a BITMAP al subirla a Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, bitmap

El problema que tengo es al subir unas imágenes mediante el chat, pero a veces estas pueden ser muy pesadas y no convendría subir imágenes tan pesadas a **Firebase**. así que opte por tomar la imagen de la `Uri` que trae el `ActivityForResult` y convertirla a `Bitmap`, pero esta al revisar en la consola de **Firebase** resulta que la imagen no perdió tamaño sino que antes aumento.

**Aquí el código:**

```
byte[] data_byte = null;
if (requestCode == PHOTO_SEND && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
    Uri u = data.getData();
    String id_grupo = getPreferences("id_grupo");
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), u);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        data_byte = bytes.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    storageReference = storage.getReference("imagenes_chat_"+id_grupo);
    final StorageReference fotoReferencia = storageReference.child(u.getLastPathSegment());
    uploadTask = fotoReferencia.putBytes(data_byte);
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());
            HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
            String name = user.get("name");
            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri u = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            MensajeEnviar m = new MensajeEnviar("Ha enviado una foto",u.toString(),name,"","2",ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            databaseReference.push().setValue(m);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas pasando mal el valor al compress, como dice en la documentación https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap

```
public boolean compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat formato, 
                int calidad, 
                OutputStream stream)
```

> int: Sugerencia al compresor, 0-100. 0 significa compresión para
>   tamaño pequeño, 100 lo que significa compresión para una calidad
>   máxima. Algunos formatos, como PNG sin pérdidas, ignorarán la
>   configuración de calidad

trata de reducir el 100 a 50 o 40 y veras que la imagen es achica

0 - Maxima compresion (menor tamaño)

100 - Poca compresion para mas calidad (mayor tamaño)

Cambia esta linea

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
```

por esto

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bytes);
```

ahi deberias notar un cambio importante en el tamaño de la imagen, aunque recuerda que cada vez que se comprime mas, mas pierde calidad, ahi es donde deberias jugar con esos valores para ver cual es tu mejor calidad/tamaño para firebase

Comment: Wow no sabia eso, muchas gracias @Gastón Saillén.

Comment: ningun problema, cualquier duda me avisas, saludos